# highcharts-export-server does not finish

Tags: node.js, highcharts, phantomjs

I have *highcharts-export-server* v2.1.0 (which uses phantomjs v.2.1.1) configured on 2 servers.

[image]

**Problem:** One server can produce a chart from my "test" .json to .svg, the other server cannot / seems stuck...

**Question:** I have already set the *logLevel* to *4*, How else can I debug this / find the error?

.

[image]

My input script is the following:

```js
{"title":{"text":"Benchmark +0.75% (Year to Date)"},"time":{"useUTC":false},"chart":{"alignThresholds":true,"width":1000,"height":400,"plotBackgroundColor":null,"plotBorderWidth":0,"plotShadow":false,"spacingRight":40},"xAxis":{"labels":{"rotation":-45}},"yAxis":[{"labels":{"format":"{value:.0f}"},"showLastLabel":true,"opposite":false,"min":-3.67256505,"max":4.93075599694519,"tickPositions":[-3.67,-2.6,-1.52,0,0.63,1.7,2.78,3.86,4.93]},{"showLastLabel":true,"gridLineWidth":0,"tickPosition":"outside","labels":{"align":"right","x":30,"style":{"color":"#ff0000"}},"min":-0.9340809915870241,"max":1.2540895500000002,"tickPositions":[-0.93,-0.66,-0.39,-0.11,0,0.16,0.43,0.71,0.98,1.25]}],"legend":{"enabled":true},"rangeSelector":{"enabled":false},"scrollbar":{"enabled":false},"navigator":{"enabled":false},"credits":{"enabled":false},"plotOptions":{"series":{"compare":"percent","showInNavigator":false}},"series":[{"compare":"amount","data":[[1609282800000,0],[1609369200000,-0.03428646532872559],[1609455600000,-0.0016039750283303178],[1609714800000,0.7637526405996908],[1609801200000,0.8005732883660022],[1609887600000,-0.1690494144598209],[1609974000000,-0.3809350266101741],[1610060400000,-1.514325071693856],[1610319600000,-0.4765023006985114],[1610406000000,-0.20592306146072215],[1610492400000,-1.6056700749591757],[1610578800000,-2.283907756098269],[1610665200000,-2.8475657141212585],[1610924400000,-2.5301565339659216],[1611010800000,-1.347913879404139],[1611097200000,-1.078254441804205],[1611183600000,-1.508647334728952],[1611270000000,-1.5661224299388987],[1611529200000,-2.280813980426055],[1611615600000,-1.9904069262878465],[1611702000000,-3.1733261828598924],[1611788400000,-2.6038661425901943],[1611874800000,-3.10474672552985],[1612134000000,-1.9489382228070617],[1612220400000,-1.4168123948971045],[1612306800000,-1.5077205238559155],[1612393200000,-1.114743473256452],[1612479600000,-1.445007216058669],[1612738800000,-1.2708019773828516],[1612825200000,-1.5637751417799883],[1612911600000,-0.9207988194119499],[1612998000000,-0.5330477534657541],[1613084400000,-1.3483873661346957],[1613343600000,-1.2824277237734494],[1613430000000,-0.8192853328358063],[1613516400000,-0.3653079990091568],[1613602800000,-0.060653517166342485],[1613689200000,0.8697340876174797],[1613948400000,1.2280953226873725],[1614034800000,1.0859394764373809],[1614121200000,1.2063367293352778],[1614207600000,0.10773414212172927],[1614294000000,-1.5207190905506263],[1614553200000,-0.9816998314673975],[1614639600000,-0.924383129032802],[1614726000000,-0.8715904396361718],[1614812400000,-0.4280745420743859]],"name":"Portfolio -0.43%"},{"compare":"amount","data":[[1609282800000,0],[1609714800000,0.8278755650112268],[1609801200000,0.7356135496841887],[1609887600000,-0.3448445224439989],[1609974000000,-0.5651564695949629],[1610060400000,-1.6946417469431263],[1610319600000,-0.6017716353404978],[1610406000000,-0.302437374178699],[1610492400000,-1.6516136459999498],[1610578800000,-2.459423156169538],[1610665200000,-2.696698045145274],[1610924400000,-2.410809781870449],[1611010800000,-1.3613816021318614],[1611097200000,-0.991919709902811],[1611183600000,-1.414545878781237],[1611270000000,-1.4817771059954743],[1611529200000,-2.3322008861873744],[1611615600000,-2.036590278127237],[1611702000000,-3.4976807891963],[1611788400000,-2.986102839764737],[1611874800000,-3.4540325607614886],[1612134000000,-2.105269707267987],[1612220400000,-1.5899676921416361],[1612306800000,-1.7726301025414615],[1612393200000,-1.5556279775712611],[1612479600000,-1.7695269895245613],[1612738800000,-1.655544008265486],[1612825200000,-1.93170951416185],[1612911600000,-1.2587762893416121],[1612998000000,-0.8789710996493616],[1613084400000,-1.718017623965562],[1613343600000,-1.6160328512600741],[1613430000000,-1.1553433147096226],[1613516400000,-0.8357362895423104],[1613602800000,-0.5901872577077749],[1613689200000,0.4652404389007492],[1613948400000,0.7387166627010888],[1614034800000,0.6296984147131646],[1614121200000,0.597220732990178],[1614207600000,-0.45944804378783566],[1614294000000,-1.952809940009137],[1614553200000,-1.430060618679485],[1614639600000,-1.3313860807479094],[1614726000000,-1.3636570533070103],[1614812400000,-1.622445786457749],[1614898800000,-1.5049462738540242],[1615158000000,-1.1762370313930126]],"name":"BENCHM  REF -1.18%"},{"data":[[1609282800000,0],[1609714800000,-0.064122924411536],[1609801200000,0.06495973868181348],[1609887600000,0.17579510798417797],[1609974000000,0.18422144298478882],[1610060400000,0.1803166752492702],[1610319600000,0.12526933464198642],[1610406000000,0.09651431271797684],[1610492400000,0.04594357104077407],[1610578800000,0.17551540007126887],[1610665200000,-0.1508676689759847],[1610924400000,-0.11934675209547274],[1611010800000,0.013467722727722453],[1611097200000,-0.08633473190139407],[1611183600000,-0.09410145594771491],[1611270000000,-0.08434532394342442],[1611529200000,0.05138690576131921],[1611615600000,0.046183351839390596],[1611702000000,0.3243546063364078],[1611788400000,0.3822366971745428],[1611874800000,0.3492858352316386],[1612134000000,0.15633148446092537],[1612220400000,0.1731552972445316],[1612306800000,0.264909578685546],[1612393200000,0.4408845043148091],[1612479600000,0.3245197734658922],[1612738800000,0.38474203088263437],[1612825200000,0.3679343723818618],[1612911600000,0.33797746992966227],[1612998000000,0.34592334618360754],[1613084400000,0.36963025783086634],[1613343600000,0.33360512748662474],[1613430000000,0.3360579818738163],[1613516400000,0.4704282905331536],[1613602800000,0.5295337405414324],[1613689200000,0.40449364871673055],[1613948400000,0.4893786599862837],[1614034800000,0.4562410617242163],[1614121200000,0.6091159963450998],[1614207600000,0.5671821859095649],[1614294000000,0.43209084945851073],[1614553200000,0.4483607872120876],[1614639600000,0.4070029517151075],[1614726000000,0.4920666136708385],[1614812400000,1.1943712443833632]],"color":"#ff0000","name":"Relative Performance +0.75%","yAxis":1,"compare":"amount","dashStyle":"ShortDash"}]}
```

This is the code I use to produce the .svg file

```
/opt/mx/reports/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/bin/cli.js -infile /opt/mx/reports/js/_testcases/stock.json -outfile /tmp/_teststockchart.svg -type svg -constr StockChart --logLevel 4
```

This is the .svg being produced:
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please test again if the server works correctly? Run the export server and add to the port url `/health`. Let me know what did you receive

Comment: You mean *--port* or *--sslPort* ? (I cannot find "health" in the documentation -> https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server)

I did both (--port /health ..), still does not finish, here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/2T7i4ng.png

Comment: (fixed my typo), same result: https://i.imgur.com/6ByPJEc.png

Comment: [Run the local version of the server]
npx ./bin/cli.js --enableServer 1
then send GET to localhost: 7801/health.
Check if port 7801 is in use.

Comment: @madepiet, Thanks but can you explain how that would help my issue? I have run my test-script adding *npx* in the beginning, same result (does not finish)

Comment: this way I wanted to check if you are really running the export server on that port the right way. Could you please tell us what is the server response to the above steps?

Comment: Well, I have run my test-script adding npx in the beginning, same result (does not finish), it sais "http server started on 0.0.0.0:7801". Here is the output: https://i.imgur.com/y2EmmLN.png

Comment: @DavidDunham please try to reinstall the whole export server package. If this solution won't work, you can try testing a new export server. If you would like to know more about it and install it from the GitHub repository - visit the link below: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/tree/enhancement/puppeteer